# Integral in cylindrical coordinates with only one differential and written basis?

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, coordinate-systems, cylindrical-coordinates

Let's say I have this integral in cylindrical coordinates:
$$\int_0^\pi 2z\rhoê_\rho d\phi$$

How is this calculated? I need some help in understanding how to interpret this integral.

1. Why is there a $ê_\rho$ after $\rho$, but not a $ê_z$ after $z$? Does the $ê_\rho$ "hold" all of the $2z\rho$ as the "coefficient"?
2. Can it then be written as a vector then, ie. $\int_0^\pi (2z\rho,0,0)d\phi$?
3. Why is there only a $d\phi$? Since there's no $\phi$ in the function (vector?), can the $2zp$ be treated as "constants" and put outside the integral? Would the answer to the integral then be $2\pi z\rho$ or $2\pi z\rho ê_\rho$
   ?

Kind of blurry questions, but the answers to them might help me understand more about coordinate basis and integrals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scalar factor $2z\rho$ is independent of $\phi$ and can be taken outside the integral, but the vector $\hat{e}_\rho$ is actually a function of $\phi$; at each point, it's the unit vector pointing in the $\rho$ direction *at that point*, so in terms of its $xyz$ components it's given by
$$
\hat{e}_\rho =
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\phi \\
\sin\phi \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
.
$$
So what you have is the integral of a vector-valued function, and you can integrate it component-wise after writing $\hat{e}_\rho$ as above.

Comment: Okay, I can see that connection. But why would I want to change ê_rho to cartesian coordinates, since the integral is for cylindrical coordinates and the differential is of phi? Is this because ê_rho is dependent on phi as the "position vector circulates around in the cylinder"? So the primitive function would then be 2zρ(sin(phi), -cos(phi), 0)? I thought ê_rho was used to describe a vector instead of the usual (2zρ, 0, 0). Could the integral be written like that as well? How would I then see that I need to convert the ê_rho to your above vector and then integrate component-wise.

Comment: @Defindun: When you integrate, you are “adding up infinitely many infinitesimal contributions”. In this case, you have a bunch of vectors to add up, and if you want to get the grand total in the $x$-direction, you add up all the $x$-components of the contributing vectors. And the same for $y$ and $z$. This makes sense, since the $x$, $y$ and $z$ directions don't change – they are the same at all points. But you can't directly add up all the components in the $\rho$ direction, because there *is* no global $\rho$ direction – it changes from point to point.

Comment: Okay, thank you! So that is because this is a vector-valued function in cylindrical coordinates, which can be written as ∫ (2zρ, 0, 0) dϕ as well? So, since its vector-valued, we have to use coordinates that remains the same, ie. are global? So we convert the "vector-direction" which depends on ϕ (since that's the differential) and can put 2zρ outside as "constants"? My question then is for regular triple integrals for example, where we integrate over ρ, ϕ, and z as they are, so to speak? What are the unit vectors for these? It is after all cylindrical coordinates as well.

Comment: @Defindun: Notation such as $(a,b,c)$ is shorthand and has to be interpreted in context. If what you mean is $a \hat{e}_x + b \hat{e}_y + c \hat{e}_z$, then you can integrate component-wise, since what you are doing is $\int (a \hat{e}_x + b \hat{e}_y + c \hat{e}_z = \hat{e}_x \int a + \hat{e}_y \int b + \hat{e}_z \int c$, pulling the constant vectors outside of the integral. But if you mean $a \hat{e}_{\rho} + b \hat{e}_{\phi} + c \hat{e}_z$, then you can't integrate component-wise, since the vectors $\hat{e}_{\rho}$ and $\hat{e}_{\phi}$ aren't constant.

Comment: @Defindun: But regarding your question about triple integrals, I don't understand what you mean. It's just standard multivariable calculus, where you integrate a scalar-valued function. A change of variables converts the original region in $xyz$-space to a new region in $r\theta\phi$-space, but it's still just an ordinary triple integral no matter what the coordinates are called.

Comment: I think I understand a bit more. Thank you! I'm sorry for the vague questions. I'm new to this and don't really know the what to ask as well. Anyway, since it is an integral of a vector-valued function then the result should be a vector and that vector, ie. the answer, in this case, would be 2zρ(0,2,0)?

Comment: @Defindun: Yep, that's right.

Comment: And just to clarify, this answer is then in cartesian coordinates, ie. the answer is $2z\rho(0\cdotê_x+2\cdotê_y+0\cdotê_z)$ in "expanded form"?

Comment: That's right too.